# Selenium fails to start Chromedriver

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to start `Chromedriver` with `Selenium`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

**It never gets to** `browser.get('http://www.google.com')` but fails with:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 3.13.0-76-generic x86_64)
```

I am on `Ubuntu 14.04` (64b) using `Python 2.7.6` (*virtualenv* installation) and `selenium==2.50.1`.

```
dm@Z580:~$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

dm@Z580:~$ ll /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 feb  4 22:13 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> /opt/google/chromedriver*
```

**EDIT**

```
dm@Z580:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 48.0.2564.97
```

Downgraded to `Chromedriver 2.20`:

```
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
chmod 777 chromedriver
sudo mv -f chromedriver /opt/google/chromedriver
```

but, sadly, still the same result.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Interesting, could not reproduce it on MacOSx, tried with both Python 2.7 and 3.5. What Chrome version do you have installed?

Comment: What if you downgrade to chromedriver 2.20?

Comment: Is that the real chromedriver file (not a foder)? Can you try this?`browser = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chromedriver')`.

Comment: how about giving executable permission to chromedriver : chmod +x chromedriver

Comment: @Pankaj I am setting permissions as `chmod 777 chromedriver`

Comment: You have to add the http://  before  www.google.com.   

`browser.get('http://www.google.com')`

Comment: @Buaban it's not a directory, only the executable is zipped; using `browser = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chromedriver')` didn't help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so the solution is a *bit weird*.

I moved the `Chromedriver` binary from `/opt/google/` (where `Google Chrome` is installed itself) to `/opt/`, updated the symlink and it's working now!

Compared to the question itself, these two lines of code solve the issue:

```
sudo mv /opt/google/chromedriver /opt/
sudo ln -fs /opt/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

And now I am able to run the following Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Chrome starts and everything.

The following line on the [old Selenium docs page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) inspired me to check and eventually to change the `Chromedriver` location:

> For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects /usr/bin/google-chrome to
>   be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the only issue you're having but chromedriver doesn't like "www.google.com", however it is fine with "http://www.google.com"

Comment: Copied from the question: It never gets to `browser.get('www.google.com')` ... But otherwise yes, good point