# Selenium fails to start Chromedriver in CentOS

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver

I try to start Chromedriver with Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
print(driver.title)
```

and error msg below:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092,platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

I am using these:

```
[root@jdu4e00u53f7 workspace]# ll /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 11月 14 00:31 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> /opt/chromedriver
```

- CentOS 7.3
- Python(3.6.2)
- selenium (3.7.0)
- Google Chrome (62.0.3202.89)
- chromedriver(2.9）/ I changed to chromedriver=2.33.506092
- Xvfb

ps, I also tried

1. `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')`,it not work...

[test.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHoQe.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8QOA.png)

ref :[Selenium fails to start Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212993/selenium-fails-to-start-chromedriver/47277494#47277494)

2. On my server start Xvfb in the background:
   `Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`
   and also not work

ref:[unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri)

Answer (score 3):

It is much evident from your mentioned configuration that you are using **`Selenium v3.7.0`**, **`Google Chrome 62.0`** along with **`chromedriver v2.9`** which is not compatible. Hence we are seeing the error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`

> The Release Notes of **`ChromeDriver v2.33`** clearly mentions **`Supports Chrome v60-62`**

### Solution:

Download the latest **`chromedriver v2.33`** from [`this link`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and execute your testcase.

### Update :

Try the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

> OR

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/opt/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to python. I tried install 2.33 this time, but still not work, 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)'

Comment: thanks for help, still failed. I add the screenshot in my question, please check in "test.py"& "output"

Comment: I am trying to work this code on a centos server, not local. I am trying use pyvirtualdisplay

Comment: This solution does not work for me, please suggest or  reopen my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274116/selenium-webdriver-exception-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-on-cent