# "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"

Tags: linux

I am trying to run this tool on kali linux. 
https://github.com/metachar/Hatch
I have downloaded everything required, and when I try to run this by giving command `python main.py`, I get this return message:
https://gist.github.com/climbpg/202e51894cc47aeae8b33d397fbf0c74

I saw other stack overflow answers that suggested downloading and running xbfv (in background??), and I was able to successfully download it, but I wasn't sure how I can run this on terminal.

Please if you have any ideas how I can run the python code, please share it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium fails to start Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212993/selenium-fails-to-start-chromedriver)

Comment: @Perplexabot unfortunately my Chrome is not downloaded in the opt directory. I actually don't even have the opt directory.

Comment: Hm, just checking. I would maybe try a simple python program with just selenium to see if you have the chromium driver in the path, and that your browser is compatible with that driver. Maybe someone else will chime in